# Examples of 302 vs 303

Tags: http, redirect

What is the difference between a `302` and `303` response?

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

- 10.3.3 302 Found
- 10.3.4 303 See Other

Are these interchangeable or why would one be used over the other? Could you please provide a use case of when one would be used (and the other would not) ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The description on the page to which you linked seem to be fairly descriptive of their intended purpose:

A 302 redirect indicates that the redirect is *temporary* -- clients should check back at the original URL in future requests.

A 303 redirect is meant to redirect a `POST` request to a `GET` resource (otherwise, the client assumes that the request method for the new location is the same as for the original resource).

If you're redirecting a client as part of your web application but expect them to always start at the web application (for example, a URL shortener), a 302 redirect seems to make sense.  A 303 redirect is for use when you are receiving `POST` data from a client (e.g., a form submission) and you want to redirect them to a new web page to be retrieved using `GET` instead of `POST` (e.g., a standard page request).

But see this note from the status code definitions -- most clients will do the same thing for either a 302 or 303:

```
  Note: RFC 1945 and RFC 2068 specify that the client is not allowed
  to change the method on the redirected request.  However, most
  existing user agent implementations treat 302 as if it were a 303
  response, performing a GET on the Location field-value regardless
  of the original request method. The status codes 303 and 307 have
  been added for servers that wish to make unambiguously clear which
  kind of reaction is expected of the client.
```

Comment: there is 308 now

Comment: I think it's a bit misleading to suggest that 303 is "meant" to redirect a POST to a GET - full stop.  The spec suggests that 303 is more about the availability of a representation of a resource via the originally requested method.  If, for example, I have a large rights-protected image only available to authenticated users, I might use a 303 to redirect unauthenticated users to a smaller image. The request method used in such a case is irrelevant.

Comment: [The RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.3.4) says "This method exists primarily to allow the output of a POST-activated script to redirect the user agent to a selected resource." and "The response to the request can be found under a different URI and SHOULD be retrieved using a GET method on that resource". I think that pretty much matches what I said (all those many years ago), but I'm sure there is room for interpretation.

Answer (score 33):

There are five different redirect types.  Originally there were only two (301 and 302) but most clients implemented them incorrectly so three more were added to clarify the difference between the two different possible behaviours.

The RFC you linked to states this in the section on 302 redirects:

> ```
>   Note: RFC 1945 and RFC 2068 specify that the client is not allowed
>   to change the method on the redirected request.  However, most
>   existing user agent implementations treat 302 as if it were a 303
>   response, performing a GET on the Location field-value regardless
>   of the original request method. The status codes 303 and 307 have
>   been added for servers that wish to make unambiguously clear which
>   kind of reaction is expected of the client.
> ```

### The original redirects

- A **301** redirect is a permanent redirect.  It is cacheable and any bookmarks for this URL should be updated to point to the new URL.
- A **302** redirect is a temporary redirect.  It is not cacheable by default and should be re-requested every time (but you can override this with caching headers).

For both of the above, the follow-up request should use the same method (POST, GET, CONNECT, PUT, DELETE, etc.) as the original request and for anything other than GET and HEAD requests, the client should prompt the user before making the request.

Unfortunately this is the part that clients sometimes get wrong and most of them change the method for the follow-up request to GET, regardless of the original method. Because of this, three more redirect codes were created:

### The newer redirects

- A **303** redirect is the same as a 302 (ie. temporary) except that the follow-up request is now explicitly changed to a GET request and no confirmation is required.
- A **307** redirect is the same as a 302 (ie. temporary) except that the follow-up request is now explicitly the same as the original request and confirmation must be acquired from the user for request methods other than GET and HEAD.
- A **308** redirect is the same as a 301 (ie. permanent) except the request method and the body will not be altered.

Modern clients should not have any issues with these newer redirects.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It should have more upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect types (301,302,303...) used have a lot of impact on how search engines will index and rank content. Some spiders might even refuse to index temporarily redirected content. Details can be found in various SEO literature...